# Accessing shared resources over LAN

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a problem with subj. 
 I'm trying to get acccess to shared resources (folders & files) at VPS hosted in LAN. Of course I can map shared as a drive, but this just isn't suitable. I need to be able to browse through folders and read/write to files.

Answer (score 1):

JCIFS is the answer if the folders are exported as Widnows shares (http://jcifs.samba.org/).

Apache Commons VFS is a common API for accessing files through a lot of different protocols (http://commons.apache.org/vfs/).